# LayoutConstraints - Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I have an app, when I click on my profile page, I kept getting these errors in my console

I have tried

[image]

This is the entire constraint that I have on my profile page

[image]

I kept getting

[image]

```
john
jane
andrew
2018-07-31 11:58:46.821640-0400 tableInTabbed[4355:5682078] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000281130 UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.width == 70   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002812c0 UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.width == UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000280d20 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cf1c7f0.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.bottom + 52.67   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002815e0 UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cf1c7f0.topMargin + 29.33   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290040 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cf1c7f0.height == 168   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002812c0 UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.width == UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.height   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-07-31 11:58:46.822304-0400 tableInTabbed[4355:5682078] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000280d20 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cf1c7f0.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.bottom + 52.67   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002815e0 UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cf1c7f0.topMargin + 29.33   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000281310 UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.height == 70   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290040 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cf1c7f0.height == 168   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000281310 UIImageView:0x7ff91cf1d030.height == 70   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-07-31 11:58:46.822846-0400 tableInTabbed[4355:5682078] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028fa00 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.width == 70   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028ff00 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.width == UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028a8c0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc13cb0.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.bottom + 52.67   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000289b50 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc13cb0.topMargin + 29.33   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290900 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc13cb0.height == 168   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028ff00 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.width == UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.height   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-07-31 11:58:46.823293-0400 tableInTabbed[4355:5682078] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028a8c0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc13cb0.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.bottom + 52.67   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000289b50 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc13cb0.topMargin + 29.33   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028fb90 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.height == 70   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290900 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc13cb0.height == 168   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028fb90 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc140c0.height == 70   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-07-31 11:58:46.823961-0400 tableInTabbed[4355:5682078] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290ae0 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.width == 70   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290b30 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.width == UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290cc0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc16840.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.bottom + 52.67   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290d60 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc16840.topMargin + 29.33   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002822b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc16840.height == 168   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290b30 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.width == UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.height   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-07-31 11:58:46.824333-0400 tableInTabbed[4355:5682078] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290cc0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc16840.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.bottom + 52.67   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290d60 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc16840.topMargin + 29.33   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290b80 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.height == 70   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002822b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff91cc16840.height == 168   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290b80 UIImageView:0x7ff91cc16a40.height == 70   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

This is what I have

```
//
//  ProfileViewController
//  tableInTabbed
//
//  Copyright © 2018 LR Web Design. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let profiles = ["john", "jane", "andrew"]
    let devicesInProfile = ["3", "5", "10"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (profiles.count)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        cell.profileImg.image = UIImage(named: profiles[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")
        cell.profileName.text = profiles[indexPath.row]

        print(profiles[indexPath.row])

        return cell

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

I just want to get rid of the error message.

### Update

@Sandeep, after trying your answer, I ended up with this final constraint

[image]

This is the result

[image]

Can you please suggest a bit more ?

Comment: I don't see any leading or trailing constraints neither from image view nor from UILAbel. Add leading constraint to UIImageView and Trailing constraint to label that should solve your problem. As far as the constraint breaks are concerned

Comment: how do I do that ? via Xcode ? or via code ?

Comment: the console log is pretty clear, your image view has height constraint of 70 and you have top and bottom constraint to cell with value 29.3 and 57.2 that means the cells height should be 70 + 29.3 + 57.2. If you have height for row At index path implemented make sure u return proper value else use automatic cell heights (UITableViewAutomaticDimension)

Comment: As far as I can see your tableView data source has provided tableView with the height of 168 where as the calculation of your existing constraints leads to 70 + 29.3 + 57.2 = 156.5. Hence while rendering there is discrepancy in height thats actually provided and what your components provide. Hence iOS breaks the height constraint of UIIMageView to render it properly. It might be helpful for you to realize that auto layout constraints are nothing more than simple mathematical equations. Try to analyze them  and u shall have your error fixed

Comment: reply to your first comment, how do I set the automatic cell height ? should I remove any restriction to my width and height ?

Comment: First thing first if you want to use automatic cell heights all you have to do is `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`
`self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160 //whatever is closer to real height; `

Comment: Second, if you want your cell to take height based on the content it has inside the components should have enough constraints on them to calculate the implicit height. In your case you have imageView that has height constraint of 70 and has top and bottom margin to contentView which is fixed, that makes the enough constraints for cell to calculate the height automatically. UILabels have implicit size by default :)

Comment: so I will add that 2 lines and try again ? should I expect the console be gone ?

Comment: the red errors in your xib though signifies much more error, which I am guessing is because of missing leading n trailing constraints. First make sure there is no error or warning in your xib and then use the two lines I suggested :) That should solve your problem

Comment: UILabels seems to be fine, I think I have issue with my image.

Comment: Thats what I said in comments above :) BTW UILabel seems to be fine because 1. UILabels have implicit size by default 2. You have aligned labels and imageView's base :)

Comment: Man styling iOS is a way more complicated than css. lol. I'm new to this mobile thing... How do people add an icon and a name on table without causing all of these issues ? Can you show me how to that please ?

Comment: Lemme add answer with constraints :)

Comment: Please so. I just want to make sure my icons, and my name is center in the my table cell all the time. https://pasteboard.co/Hx1Roll.png :D

Comment: Take a look at the detailed answer posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Drag a View to your cell and apply horizontally and vertically center constraints to to your view (This will show few constraint breaks but hang on a bit)

[image]

**Step 2:**

Drag imageView to view and apply height constraint/ aspect ratio/ leading / height and bottom constraint as shown

[image]

**Step 3:**

Drag UILabel to View preferably right side of ImageView and apply trailing constraint and leading constraint to label. Leading constraint will be to content view of cell while leading constraint to UIImageView.

Trailing Constraint to Label

[image]

Now add Leading constraint to UIImageView (Control drag from label to imageView and select horizontal spacing)

[image]

Finally control drag from label to imageView again and select center vertically

[image]

That should be it :)

If everything is fine final constraints should look like

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow, I got to say, amazing answer. ! I was able followed through and run it now.

Comment: @kyo : Am glad I could be of help :) Please consider accepting the answer if it helped :)

Comment: How do I select my final constraint and share with you since I have 2 objects, image and label ?

Comment: This is the final look I have for label. https://pasteboard.co/Hx23u5c.png

Comment: Some string was cut off, how do we adjust it so that it will fit at least 15-20 character for name ?

Comment: @kyo : Seems like you messed up some constraint buddy, have you added aspect ration to label ?? Please dont add it, finally make sure you have trailing constraint from your label to cell finally select the constraint between label and imageView and set the constraint as whatever value you need. Looks like you have dragged leading constraint you added is to cell and not to imageView make sure you have proper constraints added

Comment: @kyo : Looks like you have set very large number for horizontal spacing constraint between label and UIImageView reduce it to 8 and you will see that name is printed completely and in center of screen make sure you got rid of all red lines and warnings. In my case I dont have any warning or error in my xib

Comment: Let me try base on your last comments. meanwhile I update my result to my post base on your suggestion.

Comment: You said, `make sure you got rid of all red lines and warnings.` how do we do that  ? select it and delete it ?

Comment: @kyo : Please add constraints exactly as I have said in my answer not even single constraint more nor one less. If there exists red line please add their detail, you can see what Xcode is telling you whats wrong with the xib post it here we will be able to fix it for you. As far as I can see there is a constraint between profileName.leading = Profile image.trailing + 212. Make sure you select that constraint and set the constant value from 212 to 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177125/discussion-between-kyo-and-sandeep-bhandari).

Answer (score 1):

What have you did in your code seems to be fine, but it has nothing to do with what have you seen in the console.

First, you should know that red constraints means that there is something wrong, more specifically it means that the interface builder is unable to recognize what to achieve because there is at least one constraint missed (and that's why you are seeing these complains on the console).

Therefore, I would highly recommend to *avoid* following the approach of **"Adding Missing Constraints"** or **"Reset to Suggested Constraints"**, it is *not* an elegant option to deal with constraints; Most of the time, even if they didn't add red (missing) constraints, it won't leads to the expected result, which seems to be logical because it can't be so magical to read your mind thoughts and translate it, they could be more than just one aspect for determining the way of how to setup the constraints! Instead, do it by your self, that's the good approach for achieving what's exactly it should look/behave. Keep in mind that it is not just one static way to do it, after getting understanding the that Auto Layout works you figure that there is more than one way to achieve it.

In general, the expected result is to see blue lines (constraints) instead of red or orange.

Now, because it might be broad to describe how to setup your constraints (Auto Layout), I would suggest to check: [Understanding Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) from Apple, it is a very good place to start with.

Answer (score 0):

1- Make sure that only one path of elements from top to bottom is hooked to the contentView , if you see red lines , disconnect bottom constraint and change middle items constraints , then re-hook it again

2- Set bottom most constraint priority to 999

3- Set leading to the imageView and only the bottom - most element should be hooked to the contentView's bottom

//

Blue lines here should only be constraints with img width&height
[image]

//

Set this in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200;

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: I don't understand your diagram. What is blue line mean ? Please add more details so I can get you.

Comment: I got errors when adding your 2 lines. See it here : https://pasteboard.co/Hx1QqzS.png

Comment: @Sh_Khan, can you check your final suggestion ? Why you have a lot of red constraints ?

Comment: @AhmadF no it's required for automatic cells

Comment: @kyo sorry was busy with something may other guys complete with you